# Android Webview won't show subdomain

Tags: android, apache, webview, subdomain

I'm developping a simple android app to open a webpage of a website I'm developping.

But webview can't open a subdomain of this website ?

For instance https://example.com will work but https://www.example.com or https://reader.example.com will show me a blank page.

Thanking you all in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this solution

you can use https://example.reader.com . this solution should be works in webview.

if not works please check your Cpanel and solve the sub-domains DNS CNAME records.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfotunately it didn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Here's finally what I did :

Instead of going to reader.example.com, I created a redirection from example.com/reader to reader.example.com in Apache conf file so that I can pass the example.com/reader address to Webview.

That being done I have to manipulate the URL string a bit if paramaters are passed in the URL but it works.